# Failing to get Android sources - Connection refused

Tags: android, git, repository

I'm trying to get the Android sources according to http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html , but get the following during repo init:

```
android.git.kernel.org[0: 149.20.4.77]:errno=Connection refused
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you can always use this alternative https://github.com/android

Comment: Thank you! How updated is it?

Answer (score 0):

`android.git.kernel.org` is old and have been down for awhile. get the newest `repo` and use `android.googlesource.com`.

Comment: That's actually what I do - as described in the link. I run  repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest and it produces the error cited above.